# Api Call returning an exception

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core, monogame

I am developing a game using Monogame and I want to access my Api so that I can make a login but it always returns me an exception. If I use port 80 I get the following one  `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` and if I use port 5000 I get a `401: Not authorized` .
By printing in the console I could come to the conclusion that my try is interrupted at the line  `response = await client.GetStringAsync(builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);`
Is there something wrong with my code?

### Communication class

```
public class Communication
    {
        private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private const string Uri = "http://localhost:5000/";
        private const int Port = 5000;

        public Communication()
        {
           
        }
        public async Task<User> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            string response;
            User user = null;

            try
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(Uri + "/Api/Account/Login/")
                {
                    Port = Port
                };
                builder.Query = $"Username={username}&Password={password}";
                Debug.WriteLine("Chegou Aqui!!!!")
                response = await client.GetStringAsync(builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

                if (response == "OK")
                {

                    user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);

            }

            return user;
        }



    }
```

### My Api Login Method

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]AuthenticateModel userModel)
        {
            
            var user = _userService.Authenticate(userModel.Username, userModel.Password);

            if(user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or Password invalid" });
            }

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return Ok(new
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                UserName = user.Username,
                Token = tokenString
            }) ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.smartftp.com/en-us/support/kb/58) possibly can help you

You can check your firewall settings or if any antivirus installed in your system, make sure to check the settings of it.

You get error `401: Not authorized` because HTTP requests by default configured on port 80, not any other ports.

If the problem persists, check your router or switch configuration, if any is in your route to server.